# ¿Cómo puedo validar el campo nombre?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una aplicación la cual inserta datos de monitores, y uno de los campos es el nombre.Me gustaría que permitiese insertar nombres como Sara Paz Seda.¿Cómo podría realizar dicho código? Este es el ejemplo que estoy usando pero no funciona correctamente :

```
public static boolean validarNombre(String nombre) {
    boolean correctoNombre = false;
    if (nombre.matches("^ ([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+[ ]? ){1,3}$")) {
        correctoNombre = true;
    }
    return correctoNombre;
 }
```

Comment: Acepta todo. _Nombres_ pueden ser _cualqiera sea_. Lo único debese hacer es verificar que dos diferentes personas no se confuden por tener el mismo nobre. Una lectura buena es [Falsedades que los programadores crean sobre los nombres](https://shinesolutions-com.translate.goog/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

Comment: Oh, también, siempre trata los nombres como texto no seguro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Para validar el ejemplo que nos has dado lo tenías mal escrito el regex. Me explico:

Primero el espacio después ^ te marca se interpreta de forma literal y el de después del ?, también. Por tanto, te interpretaba (espacio)Sara(espacio)(espacio)Paz(espacio)(espacio)(Paeda) lo cual no encajaba con el string.

```
^([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+[ ]?){1,3}$
```

Para poder validar te dejo [link](https://regex101.com/) de una web para eso.